# Excel VBA Fastest way to do look up and replace

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has a main sheet that a JSON is loaded into. It has 6 columns of UUIDs about a 1000 rows long that I need to cross reference from 3 other sheets and replace the UUIDs with their corresponding value. This only does 4 of the columns and I have another 2 to go. At this time it takes about 23 seconds to run. I have created the following code which works but is to slow. Can anyone help me speed this up?

```
Sub UUID_Replace()

Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
Dim Ws4 As Worksheet

Dim staffData As Variant
Dim clientData As Variant
Dim categoryData As Variant
Dim staffLastRow As Long
Dim clientLastRow As Long
Dim categoryLastRow As Long

Dim ColumnUUID As Range
Dim jobLastRow As Long
Dim jobValue As String
Dim joblastCol As Long
Dim jobCell As Range
Dim jobcolrange As Variant
    
Dim cellValue As String
Dim i As Long

Dim LookUpDict As Object

Dim startTime As Double
Dim stopTime As Double

startTime = Timer

Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("job")
Set Ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("staff")
Set Ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("category")
Set Ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("client")

Set LookUpDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
joblastCol = Ws1.Cells(1, Ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
jobLastRow = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
jobcolrange = Ws1.Range(Ws1.Cells(1, 1), Ws1.Cells(jobLastRow, joblastCol)).value

staffLastRow = Ws2.Cells(Ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
staffData = Ws2.Range("A2:B" & staffLastRow).value

clientLastRow = Ws4.Cells(Ws4.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
clientData = Ws4.Range("A2:C" & clientLastRow).value

categoryLastRow = Ws3.Cells(Ws3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
categoryData = Ws3.Range("A2:C" & categoryLastRow).value

For i = 1 To UBound(staffData)
    LookUpDict(staffData(i, 1)) = staffData(i, 2)
Next i

For i = 1 To joblastCol
    cellValue = jobcolrange(1, i)
    If InStr(1, cellValue, "actioned_by", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, cellValue, "created_by", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set ColumnUUID = Ws1.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
        For Each jobCell In ColumnUUID.Cells
            jobValue = jobCell.value
            If LookUpDict.Exists(jobValue) Then
                jobCell.value = LookUpDict(jobValue)
            End If
        Next jobCell
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(clientData)
    LookUpDict(clientData(i, 1)) = clientData(i, 3)
Next i

For i = 1 To joblastCol
    cellValue = jobcolrange(1, i)
    If InStr(1, cellValue, "company_uuid", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set ColumnUUID = Ws1.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
        For Each jobCell In ColumnUUID.Cells
            jobValue = jobCell.value
            If LookUpDict.Exists(jobValue) Then
                jobCell.value = LookUpDict(jobValue)
            End If
        Next jobCell
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(categoryData)
    LookUpDict(categoryData(i, 1)) = categoryData(i, 3)
Next i

For i = 1 To joblastCol
    cellValue = jobcolrange(1, i)
    If InStr(1, cellValue, "category_uuid", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set ColumnUUID = Ws1.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
        For Each jobCell In ColumnUUID.Cells
            jobValue = jobCell.value
            If LookUpDict.Exists(jobValue) Then
                jobCell.value = LookUpDict(jobValue)
            End If
        Next jobCell
    End If
Next i
stopTime = Timer
Debug.Print stopTime - startTime

    Set LookUpDict = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't populate the dictionary with data from all sheets, and then just run one replace loop?

Comment: `Set ColumnUUID = Ws1.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn` FYI this will loop over the whole column (>1M cells)  `Set ColumnUUID = Ws1.Cells(1, i).Resize(Ws1.Cells(Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Row)` would skip empty rows

Comment: Thank you again Tim Williams, this is exactly what I needed it cut the time by 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set ColumnUUID = Ws1.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn`

FYI this will loop over the whole column (>1M cells)

`Set ColumnUUID = Ws1.Cells(1, i).Resize(Ws1.Cells(Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Row)`

will skip empty rows.

You could also fill the dictionary from all 3 sheets and then loop once over your data to make any replacements.